# How to handle a rejected call to `screen.orientation.unlock()` on firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, error-handling, screen

The [spec](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#unlock-method-unlock-screen-to-default-orientation) states that a call to `screen.orientation.unlock()` returns void.

However Firefox throws an internal "Not supported" exception on the desktop browser.

Because nothing is returned, the following approaches do not appear to work:

```
screen
  .orientation.unlock()
  .catch(error => console.error('[Screen orientation]', error))
```

```
try {
  screen.orientation.unlock()
} catch (error) {
  console.error('[Screen orientation]', error)
}
```

Is there a way to handle / suppress this error?